# Why close() method in java are throwing exception?

Tags: java, exception

really stupid question but maybe somebody has a smart answer :

why close() methods in Java throw exceptions ?

in my opinion close() is the final method you call in some kind of logic so it should not fail, even if it fails something it should be treated in the Class and not throw the Exception.

thanks ALL

PS : mostly the question is about object design and development approach (not implementation specific)

now you probably are right that this makes sense, but how to write nicely this kind of code:

```
try {
} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error("Error occured during copy", e);
} finally {
    // close all objects
    try {
        connection.close();
    } catch ( ... ) {
        ...
    } finally {
        ...
    }
}
```

thanks.

Comment: the `close()` method of which class do you mean?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code, and the specific exception.

Comment: can you be more specific what are you trying to close and in which class it belongs

Comment: post the code and the exception you're seeing.

Comment: very many close() methods do this, this is more like abstract question, not specific to something (ex : Sockets, Streams, Jms, Database Result Sets / COnenctions)

Comment: You mean this interface declaration? [AutoCloseable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html)

Comment: mostly the question is about object design and development approach (but maybe i'm just tired)

Comment: Possibke duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26459988/is-it-meaningful-for-autocloseables-close-method-to-throw-an-exception-how-sho

Answer (score 5):

> In my opinion `close()` is the final method you call in some kind of logic so it should not fail, even if it fails something it should be treated in the Class and not throw the Exception.

It is good to have opinions.  Unfortunately, opinions are not always sound :-)

Consider what happens when you close a `FileOutputStream` wrapped in a `BufferedOutputStream`:

1. Any outstanding data in the buffer is flushed.
2. The underlying file descriptor is 'closed'.

The first of those operations *could* fail, for example, if the file system is full.

Now imagine that the application was writing a critical file; e.g. an "adduser" program that updates "/etc/passwd" on a UNIX / Linux system.  Naturally, the application is going to do this in two steps.  First it will write out the new version of the file.  Then if that succeeds, it will rename the new file to the pathname of the old file.  (Or something like that)

But if we implemented `close()` as you want it, the application level would not know that the `close()` had failed to write all of the data out ... and the "adduser" would proceed to rename the new *incomplete* "passwd" file on top of the old version.  Ooops!!  You've just trashed the "/etc/passwd" and nobody can log in any more.  (I hope you've got a backup tape handy :-) )

**Lesson:** the `IOExceptions` thrown by `close()` may be important.

---

> You are right of course, but something doesn't feel right in writing that structure.

Well, the "try-with-resources" syntax makes this nicer.  However, you **cannot** avoid dealing with the `IOException` at some level, unless you have the freedom to declare that `close()` on the static type of `connection` doesn't throw the exception.

The try-with-resources version would look like this:

```
try (Connection c1 = openConnection(); 
     Connection c2 = openConnection()) {
   // so stuff
}
```

Both `c1` and `c2` will be closed, even if one of their `close()` methods throws an exception.  But you will still need to deal with that exception; e.g. in an enclosing handler.  (Interesting things happen when exceptions are thrown inside the `try` *and* in the resource closing; see the section on "Suppressed Exceptions" in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html.)

Comment: you are right of course, but something doesn't feel right in writing that structure

Answer (score 3):

There are many classes that do not involve close operation, such as data objects, maps, lists, because resource management is simple for those objects.

Those classes that offer a close operation usually involve more complicated resource management. Quite often they involve buffering techniques.

Take file writer for example - on Close, buffered file content should be persisted by synchronizing with the file, but it may fail due to IO failures. Not letting failures to silent - therefore it may throw an exception to let you know.

Answer (score 2):

Generally Speaking , An IOException will be thrown on close if the final flush fails. and this can take place for many reasons . Lets say ,  you have OutputStream that for some reason hasn't written to the file yet. Invoking  close() will flush out the data, but if the file is locked - then an IOException would be raised.

Comment: If the file was locked before an open-for-write request was issued, that request should have been denied.  If a file is open for writing, outside attempts to lock the file should fail.  A better example of a problem scenario would be a yanking a USB drive between the last request to "write" a file and the request to "close" it.  No earlier operation would have had any reason to fail, but the close couldn't possibly succeed.  The only choices are to throw the exception, or let the user falsely believe the file was properly written.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write that more nicely, you can use the try-with-resource include with Java7:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
   return br.readLine();
}
```

It let's you define a resource, like an OutputStream for example that will be automatically closed at the end of your try.

Doesn't change how it works under the hood but it's more elegant.

Comment: A *major* feature of try-with-resources which would be a major pain to try to implement any other way is that an exception which occurs during a `close` will be suppressed *only* if another exception is pending.  In many cases, it would be appropriate and helpful for `close` to throw an exception in case of a usage error (e.g. if any transaction which is started with a transaction wrapper is supposed to be either committed or rolled back before the wrapper is closed, having an attempt to close without a commit or rollback throw an exception may be more helpful than a silent rollback, but...

Comment: ...if an exception which occurs during a transaction causes a `close` to occur without a commit or rollback having been requested, having the `close` throw an exception would--except when used in a try-with-resources--cause the other exception to be lost.

Answer (score -1):

`close()` function will also throw an exception in case the connection you are trying to close doesn't exist. E.g. in a JDBC SQL connection, a connection may not have opened in the first place due to incorrect JDBC URL or Username or Password, the close() function will throw an exception in this case.

Comment: Poor example. The JDBC `Connection` wouldn't exist if the connect failed, as the connect *either* fails *or* returns a `Connection` object.