# Is it meaningful for AutoCloseable's close method to throw an exception? How should this be handled?

Tags: java, c#, exception, idisposable, autocloseable

In C#, it is [considered](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386039.aspx) bad [practice](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/tools/gendarme/rules/exceptions/#donotthrowinunexpectedlocationrule) to throw exceptions in the `Dispose` method of an `IDisposable`.

By contrast, in java the `close` method of `AutoCloseable` allows any Exception whatsoever to be thrown and forces the caller to handle it somehow. But what is the caller reasonably expected to do if this happens? This suggests that the attempt to close the resource failed somehow. So does the user have to try to close the resource again before continuing, perhaps with some sort of exponential backoff?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679409/how-to-properly-handle-an-ioexception-from-close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like every operation involving the resources, including the implicit close() invocation, is considered part of the try{} block.  Even thought technically/syntactically, the resources are mentioned outside the {} braces.

Meaning that if an IOException gets thrown during the close(), it will get caught by some catch() clause associated with your try (or it will propagate up).

About the *reason* why exceptions might need to be thrown : close() might cause flush(), flush() might cause write()s, and write()s might fail.

Comment: If I have

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
        return br.readLine();
    }

and `br.close()` throws an exception, then I won't be able to try closing the resource again at the point where I have to handle the exception. This would seem to suggest that it is not necessary to try to close the resource again.

Comment: Yes. Another way to think about it is that while we are used to writing try-catch-finally, with implicit close it's more like try-finally-catch - the cleanup code is executed *before* the catch, and may generate an exception that the catch might want to handle.

Answer (score 1):

The design of `AutoCloseable` is a result of Java's checked exceptions. Some implementations simply have to be able to throw checked exceptions, and so `throws Exception` is needed. However, [implementations should declare more specific types thrown](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) (if any):

> While this interface method is declared to throw `Exception`, implementers are *strongly* encouraged to declare concrete implementations of the `close` method to throw more specific exceptions, or to throw no exception at all if the close operation cannot fail.

You shouldn't throw exceptions if there's a way of avoiding it, but you can't always avoid it. For example, when closing a [`BufferedOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html) with unflushed data, the buffered stream has two options; ignoring the unwritten data and close, or writing it to the stream, which can cause exceptions to be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Because Java's designers were able to see the issues that arose with cleanup-exception handling in .NET's `using` blocks before implementing their own try-with-resources feature, they were able to improve upon it.  In .NET, the author of a `Dispose` block is often faced with an unpleasant choice between swallowing any exceptions which occur, thus erroneously letting the calling program believe everything is fine, or letting exceptions percolating out from `Dispose` in such fashion as to obliterating any evidence of any previous exception.  Fortunately, Java avoids that issue.

If a try-with-resources block succeeds normally and the `close` also succeeds normally, then the outside code sees everything as normal.  If an exception occurs in the `try` portion but the `close` succeeds normally, the outside code will see the try-block exception.  If the `try` completes normally but the `close` throws, the outside code will see the `close` exception.  And if `try` throws, but `close` also throws, then outside code will see the `try` exception but also be able to retrieve any exception that occurred within `close` (and if multiple nested try-with-resources throw exceptions during `close`, all thrown exceptions will be available to the outside code).

Consequently, unlike the .NET design which often compels authors to stifle some potentially-serious exceptions thrown by `Dispose`, Java's design favors having `close` throw an exception any time something goes sufficiently wrong that the caller shouldn't be allowed to believe that everything's fine.

Comment: These are called "Suppressed Exceptions" in Java and Throwable has accessors for them.  See the "Suppressed Exceptions" section of https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: @SensorSmith: Feel free to edit in such details as a footnote.  My experience with Java predates try-with-resources, so I'd rather such a footnote be written by someone better qualified than myself.