# Try with Resources: Resource leak while closing resources in TWR block

Tags: java, java-7, try-with-resources, resource-leak

I read that we need not close an resource explicitly , it will be closed by java itself, let's say if i have written a code .

```
try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("");){
  // code to to somethings
}
```

the FileInputStream will be automatically closed , if while closing it generates an error , it will suppress that expression.

So if while closing an FileInputStream an exception is thrown, since the exception will be suppressed , the resource is not closed, Will it generate a resource leak ?

Comment: Note that it will only suppress the exception if an exception is thrown from the try block. The suppressed exception is still available by calling [`getSuppressed()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getSuppressed%28%29) on the thrown exception.

Comment: See  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26459988/is-it-meaningful-for-autocloseables-close-method-to-throw-an-exception-how-sho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So if while closing an `FileInputStream` an <s>expression</s> exception is generated, since the <s>expression</s> exception will be suppressed , the resource is not closed...

You don't *know* it isn't closed, just that you got an exception while closing it.

> ... Will it generate a resource leak ?

It may or may not create a leak, but there's nothing you can do about it. If you've tried to close the resource, you've done your job.

But [JB Nizet makes a very important point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28135427/try-with-resources-resource-leak-while-closing-resources-in-twr-block/28135444#comment44642938_28135427): The exception is only suppressed **if** some other exception is thrown within the `try` block (or within a `finally` block attached to it). If there's no exception during the `try` (or `finally`), an exception closing the resource *won't* be suppressed.