# If an IOException occurs while invoking close(): is the stream closed anyway?

Tags: java, exception, stream

In Java if I close a steam with close() and an exception occurs, is it closed as if no exception occurred? Or is it opens still?

Comment: Probably depends on the stream and the circumstances.

Comment: You might read this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21191562/why-close-method-in-java-are-throwing-exception

Comment: @Tim: really interesting, that link.. but finally does not answer my question... or did I oversee something. It is clear that the exception is significant. But anyway, is the stream close or is it not?

Comment: Depends on the stream. And what will you do with this information? You probably shouldn't try closing it again.

Comment: Right.  The answer is indeterminate.  In point of fact, it is very, very uncommon for `close` to throw an exception, partly because there is no good way to recover.

Comment: @eliott maybe thats why i ask: I have the notion that trying again does not help. 
But how then to recover? 
Maybe I asked the wrong question: maybe the question is how to treat with exceptions in close().... I also think trying again is no option. So leave unclosed? Or is it closed already although something went wrong?

Comment: @Tom: I can imagine it is rare, but my question is quite general. 

I found that not all Streams may throw an IOException during close().

Comment: There's not much you can do to recover, but there are different ways to respond to it. If you're calling `close` after some other IO error, you might choose to ignore the failure entirely. If it's at the end of some successful operation, you might want to log the error and move on. If it happens in the middle of a multi-stage process, you might have to abort. It all varies by case.

Answer (score 2):

The technically correct answer: **There is no way to tell**.

The useful, pragmatic answer: **Irrelevant**, *unless* we are talking about badly written filter streams in which case: Very relevant - this is why you should safely invoke `close()` on the underlying stream. And, bad news.. `java.util.ZipOutputStream` is badly written.

An object that throws IOEx in its close method cannot be used for anything useful for all relevant implementations of such things. Which object representing some resource has useful things left to do when even `close()` no longer works? The only obvious answer is a do-it-all class that mixes multiple unrelated jobs into a single class, which, well, there is no fix for working with boneheaded code other than to cease its use.

That makes things a lot easier to reason about, as there are now only three options left:

1. The resource does not *itself* represent an actual resource that needs closing. It just has a `close()` method for inheritance reasons. An example of such a class is `ByteArrayInputStream`; its `close()` method does nothing relevant and it isn't a leak in any way if you fail to call this. It's just that, well, it's an `InputStream`, and all inputstreams are defined as being AutoClosable, therefore they can't not have a `close()` method. You can check the source: It does nothing.
2. The resource directly represents a resource, i.e. a thing you got from the system from a limited pool, and failure to close it is a severe issue. Think 'file handle' or 'open network port'.
3. The resource does not *itself* represent an actual resource, but it *does* wrap around one, i.e. it is a so-called filter stream (or filter reader / filter writer). As is common in all such filterstreams, calling `close()` on them also calls `close()` on the thing it wraps. There are *many* such types: `BufferedInputStream`, `PrintWriter`, `Scanner` - just a handful of examples.

Taking them in order:

### 1. Non-resources

It doesn't matter. Nothing is lost if you fail to close these in the first place. Half of these don't even *have* a 'closed' status (such as `ByteArrayInputStream`). The rest have it only as a 'flag' that means: If any code attempts to read/write to this, throw something.

### 2. real resources

This one seems complex but is also easy: You called `close()`. This fails. That means the OS-level resource (the open network port, or the file handle) **is already gone**. There is no need to worry about it. Given that `close()` is an abstract concept (it 'closes the resource' and the specs are non-specific as to what that means *exactly*) it is theoretically possibly for an OS-level-resource-representing-object to start throwing in its `close()` method without actually closing the resource, but I doubt any exist in the JVM. Even if so, there's nothing you can do about it other than call `System.exit();`. It, again, doesn't matter.

### 3. Filter resources

This is the trickiest case, and the only one where you may actually have to act.

In researching this answer, **I found a bug in the OpenJDK** - while only badly written filter resources are an actual problem, OpenJDK's very own `ZipOutputStream` is one of those badly written ones!

---

Filter resource `close()` methods generally first `flush()` (i.e. clean up and push anything it buffered down to the underlying stream), and then call `close()` on the underlying stream. It is possible that the flush procedure itself causes an exception. I checked BufferedReader and Scanner: **They do not suffer from this issue**. They attempt to flush, and will then close the underlying resource whether the flushing worked out or not (it wraps its own underlying stream in a try-with-resources block). **However, `ZipOutputStream` does! Its `close()` method closes the currently witten zip entry, then closes the zip file which writes the content metadata, and then `close()`s the underlying stream** - and none of it guarded with try-with or any other `finally` usage.

The spec is not all that specific that you *have* to do it this way. And obviously the compiler cannot compile-time-enforce that filter resources work this way. Hence, I rate the odds that anything is going to happen when I report what is clearly a bug to the OpenJDK team as low. They tend to thump the specs and not think much more about things, in my experience. EDIT-UPDATE: I filed a bug report with ID 9075756; we'll see if it is accepted.

The problem in such a case is that if the cleanup process (such as writing the zip content metadata) causes an exception, `close()` is never invoked on the underlying stream.

However, this is relevant only if you use a certain style which isn't common, and which actively causes many linter tools to complain. I would argue that these linters are broken and shouldn't be complaining, though.

### The common style (not broken)

Looks like:

```
try (
  var rawOut = Files.newOutputStream(somePath);
  var zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(rawIn);
) {
  code here
}
```

If that's what you do (and this is the common style), then the issue about badly written filter streams (such `ZipOutputStream` here) isn't relevant: The try-with statement will end up invoking `zipOut.close()` when code exits the block, and *even if that ends up throwing*, it will then proceed to invoke `rawOut.close()` too. Your file handle is released.

### The uncommon style (BROKEN!)

Looks like:

```
try (
  var zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(somePath))) {
  code here
}
```

Lots of tutorials tend to use this style. It works fine, **if** the filter streams do their job right. This 'job' entails:

- Do not, under any circumstances, throw an exception inside your constructor. Just copy stuff to local fields. Only exception (heh) is throwing an NPE if *every* stream passed to it is `null`, i.e. `new ZipOutputStream(null)` can throw an NPE without breaking this rule.
- In your `close()` method, run `close()` on the underlying stream safely, e.g. with `try (OutputStream o = rawOut) { flush(); }` which is what `BufferedOutputStream` does.

Many baked in filterstreams do this. Unfortunately, `ZipOutputStream` does not. If a filter stream adheres to this rule this snippet is just as safe and easier to read, with fewer tainted variables (no need to discuss the proper names of each 'level' of stream, you can just call this `out`. In contrast, the first snippet risks accidentally writing to `rawOut` which would result in a completely broken method).

Many linter tools flag this code as invalid, though. Perhaps that explains why this style is not all that common.

I tend to advocate the second snippet. I shall cease doing this, given ZipOutputStream's errors.

Comment: UPDATE: I have written a self-contained test case showing how ZipOutputStream doesn't close its underlying stream if an exception is thrown during flush, whereas BufferedOutputStream does, and filed a bug with this. Its internal ID is 9075756 - once (if?) the bug team confirms it I'll try and update this answer and include a link to it.